# Bibliotecas ntddk.h e wdf.h... sabem me dizer sua utilidade nesse código?

Tags: c, biblioteca, driver

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    KdPrintEx(( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n" ));
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd);
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(_In_ WDFDRIVER Driver, _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    KdPrintEx(( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n" ));
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ntddk.h>` é o cabeçalho do **NT Driver Development Kit**, o kit de desenvolvimento de *drivers* do (Windows) NT. Ele define vários tipos de dados necessários para escrever *drivers* num ambiente de Windows NT4 ou superior (`NTSTATUS`, por exemplo). A [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548158(v=vs.85).aspx), no entanto, recomenda que se inclua a biblioteca `<wdm.h>` em vez disso — supõe-se que, ao menos, nos casos que não se usa `<wdf.h>`, abaixo.

`<wdf.h>` é a **Windows Driver Frameworks**, a [nova API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557565(v=vs.85).aspx) de *drivers* da Microsoft. Ela provê outros tipos de dados, como o `WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG` e o `WdfDriverCreate()`, e é essencialmente a API principal usada no *driver* do seu exemplo.